# Access to Kubernetes container logs programmatic

Tags: kubernetes

Is there an API method in [kubernetes-client](https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client) to access container logs? Similar to what `kubectl logs` does, only with API, to reuse authentication and not to spawn external process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like that option was added late last year:
https://github.com/fabric8io/kubernetes-client/pull/261